# bootstrap/css not rendering in Ruby on Rails in Docker

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Fellow techies,

I have been building a ruby on rails application with embedded ruby and twitter bootstrap(bootstrap-sass) all of which is working correctly when tested locally(rails server) and when deployed to heroku.

However, I have been trying to dockerize the application into a 3 tier environment(until I scale out) with docker / docker-compose. When I deploy into the container the app is working completely with the exception of the CSS / bootstrap layout. Please note I am not going through

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

**application.html loaded from index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AlphaBlog</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/stylesheets/application.css">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
    
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Failed state(docker): rendered html in chrome dev tools**

```html
<head>
<title>AlphaBlog</title>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="exrph+jdoTdpHC6INECT3nWN0TWDSREEJzGsbCf2kd9cZlhhbzBGnwxVPhmnWvwfAgARvgNcpOL5Fya0phyjKQ==" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/stylesheets/application.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/application.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<script src="/javascripts/application.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
</head>
```

**Successful state(localhost): rendered html in chrome dev tools**

```html
<head>
<title>AlphaBlog</title>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="S9mIfrj9dJGNEAzK39YlhEr9yaDgLiP/uPlJtAuUKycquMISZpccd3jsWM53+AQrYMStnFsugXdSL2pGPc5/kg==" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/stylesheets/application.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-4b6d90fa3b36a5c34ccc95f67aaf8ba9729bf9bebbd5c39399b8390ebe0bd2dd.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-ddb161abf5f419c38cbe3e77258e87cef5c121f34e0c7f21d1b1130d7be306eb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-6ad2488465135ab731a045a8ebbe3ea2fc501aed286042496eda1664fdd07ba9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-742145c5bb847aafdadc6e339be795628f8bc25f177e851f03a8c42278eb0312.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-126ac9bf0e7f2d8568f8da3a00fd5f0fac6eae0946331003370161fbf8d7975e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-e47323f363ceb3dc0bdbce05e36e709ed428e339833a41140a85cb0af24b8127.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-2eb697f62b587bb786ff940d82dd4be88cdeeaf13ca128e3da3850c5fcaec301.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-561cca1cbaf67474e01e9536f106bad541594860a6df997004591c1c1957a147.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-3e78617ade5663314b7ee0ea10375a5b34d59ffbade44939e3f2a4e4ef2019b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-5bf7078b682f8b131332eefa46b45fa5eff2eca745fc0d03e2991450888f7c28.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-6d6f1a7fc5c8aabf3547fa1b794fab6268f54bc55ad815e55873c71f52513517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-969f3c5f48cdf1e439c7fa1154c13b948715f5c689f87837c0b64521d3b46ef6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-05afb177e08f98997ccfc84fa08a215e4b27d48d5fe4d049080675e9dffd8199.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-0aa93860b59fe7393f1dd490f54b3cb994f9d6155adffce034d4e14ae361b041.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-5454023407ffec0d29137c7110917e1e745525ae9afbc05f52104c4cd6597429.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-6e0514260c1aa76eaf252412ce74e63f68819fd19bf740595f592c5ba4c36537.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-9b9be17d3c356f1a9a23b03b3b5d01bb4e46845459cc7ac189cd20f571fefb23.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not precompiling my assets in docker, this did not take place when putting together my dockerfile. I was able to find the answer below.

[Rails 4.1.6 Asset pipeline not loading assets and javascript in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752252/rails-4-1-6-asset-pipeline-not-loading-assets-and-javascript-in-production/43245272#43245272)